# Site spontaneously started failing with 403 on POST, have tried 'EVERYTHING*'

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, post

(* Well, everything sensible that I can THINK of! ;) )

I've been beating my face against a 403 forbidden error for a couple of days now. The server guys have looked at 'everything' and reckon it's a code problem.

I've now pared this down to the absolute bare bones and eliminated all that I can think of that might cause this.
I have two debug files files.

[debug.php, contains ONLY]

```
<form id = "submitorder" name = "submitorder" action="debug1.php" method="POST">
<input type = "text" value = "hello world" name = "helloworld"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Proceed to Payment." />     
</form>
```

[debug1.php, contains ONLY]

```
<?php
echo $_POST['helloworld']
?>
```

I then put the same files into the root of the site and in the plugin directory. The permissions for the directories and files are okay. (755)

If I go to: 
http://www.clinicalpocketreference.com/wp-content/plugins/owh_storefront/debug.php
it fails
if I go to 
http://www.clinicalpocketreference.com/debug.php
it works.

I have emptied .htaccess in case there was anything funny that WordPress was doing, and php.ini only contains errors = on

Occam's razor suggests that in the absence of anything funky in the code and the same code working in different folders that this can only be a server behavior.

This problem spontaneously started to happen on a site that was running without problems for over a year. WordPress and all plugins are up to date.

===edit===
The server guys are adamant that it's not a server issue, so I tried some more tests.

I tried making a folder with the same path on another WP site and copying just those two debug files and it works there.

I have since tried putting the two files into a plugin folder called debug (so there are no other files to interfere) and it fails.

I then tried putting them into each folder back along the path all the way to public_html

```
/public_html/wp-content/plugins

/public_html/wp-content
```

and these all fail apart from the ones in the root.

I then tried creating:

```
/public_html/debug
```

and the files WORK in there. The problem seems to happen whenever the code runs in a folder under wp-content. As I have a BLANK .htaccess and as I'm also just executing the debug.php file, there really isn't any other code that's running that can interfere with this. Wordpress is simply out of the picture here. All the permissions for those folders are 755

The plugin is one we developed here by the way... and of course just putting the two files into the /public_html/wp-content/plugins/debug folder eliminates any coding issues with the rest of the plugin.

There are also no .htaccess files in any of the folders along the path to the debug code.

Comment: Based on what you've stripped it down to I can't see that it's a coding issue. http://www.clinicalpocketreference.com/wp-content/plugins/owh_storefront/debug1.php is accessible via GET, but not via POST. Unless there is a .htaccess file somewhere that is interfering this looks to me like a server configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks, yep, I also found that a GET would work. I scanned the whole site for other .htaccess files and they DO exist but not anywhere in the path of the file that's failing. I pushed it back to the server guys.

Comment: Incidentally (thanks, Steve for the suggestion) I tried changing the action to notdebug1.php (which doesn't exist) and I still get a 403, NOT a 404... huh? What witchcraft is this???

Comment: So, after duplicating the files on another site on the same server (the test works!), I can only conclude so far that the POST fails with 403 to a PHP file ONLY in wp-content and its subdirectories on this particular account. It works anywhere else. permissions are 755 all down the line, no extra .htaccess and if I change the action to an HTML file, it succeeds to load the page. HOW can this just not work in one directory!!! Pint of beer to the first answer that fixes this!

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be an issue with broken files, most probably the website got hacked. If needed I can scan all your files to check if it was hacked (free of charge)